# Javascript infinite loop with delay

Tags: javascript, loops, delay, infinite

i want to make an infinite loop with a 3 time delay, but it still crashes, this is the code i've made:

```
function Main() {
    while(true) {
            setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Hello")
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()`

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous. The loop doesn't wait for the delay to finish, it just runs infinitely all at once, creating an infinite number of of timers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setTimeout` and `loops` use `setInterval` . For more details see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) guide

Working example =>

```
function Main(delay) {
  setInterval(()=> {
    console.log("Hello")
  }, delay)
}

Main(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function Main() {
        while(true) {
                setInterval(() => {
                console.log("Hello")
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
```

The function is only executed once when you use setTimeout(). If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval() method. The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals

Comment: This code will crash the browser exactly like OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` over `setTimeout`:

```js
function Main() {
  setInterval(() => console.log("Hello"), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const main = (delay) => setInterval(() => console.log('Hello World'), delay)

main(3_000);
```

One-liners are better.