# Javascript eventListener inside while loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop, event-listener

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible in Javascript to implement an eventListener into a while loop which can pass a value to a variable inside the loop. I need this to cancel an infinite loop which continiously should send a data frame to a TCP-socket (watchdog). When the socket is closed the loop should end. I use a webworker for this purpose, but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```js
// WebWorker with infinite loop

var check = "true";
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
var returnedEvent;

while (check) {

  self.postMessage(i);

  onmessage = (event) => {
    returnedEvent = event.data;
    console.log("worker: " + event.data);
    let check = returnedEvent;
  }

  sleep(100);
}

console.log("loop completed");

function sleep(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

Comment: never do sleep like that......

Comment: use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.   Not a direct answer to your question (or maybe it is, hard to tell) here's a question on an infinite loop:  [javascript infinite loop with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364493/javascript-infinite-loop-with-delay)  If you keep the return of `var t = setInterval(...)` you can pass it to `clearInterval(t);` later

Comment: You also only want to set up a *single* event handler.  Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/L9s1t0zf/), but as your code is part of a larger code, again, hard to tell, so not a full answer.

Comment: `var check = "true";` what's the other state? because `while("false")` won't end the loop; `"false"` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value

Comment: You are right. The truthy value should read ‘var check = true;’ while the corresponding falsy value is ‘returnedEvent = false;’ which can will end the loop.